# HttpWebRequest Vs HttpClient

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have a chunk of code that works using a **HttpWebRequest** and **HttpWebResponse** but I'd like to convert it to use **HttpClient** and **HttpResponseMessage**.

This is the chunk of code that works...

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceReq);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?><root><login><user>flibble</user>" + 
    @"<pwd></pwd></login></root>";
request.ContentLength = xml.Length;
using (StreamWriter dataStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    dataStream.Write(xml);
    dataStream.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And this is the code that I'd like to replace it with, if only I could get it working.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate the user credentials held as member variables
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the user credentials are valid, else false</returns>
public bool ValidateUser()
{
    bool valid = false;

    try
    {
        // Create the XML to be passed as the request
        XElement root = BuildRequestXML("LOGON");

        // Add the action to the service address
        Uri serviceReq = new Uri(m_ServiceAddress + "?obj=LOGON");


        // Create the client for the request to be sent from
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Initalise a response object
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            // Create a content object for the request
            HttpContent content = HttpContentExtensions.
                CreateDataContract<XElement>(root);

            // Make the request and retrieve the response
            response = client.Post(serviceReq, content);

            // Throw an exception if the response is not a 200 level response
            response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();

            // Retrieve the content of the response for processing
            response.Content.LoadIntoBuffer();

            // TODO: parse the response string for the required data
            XElement retElement = response.Content.ReadAsXElement();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(Category.Serious, 
            "Unable to validate the Credentials", ex);
        valid = false;
        m_uid = string.Empty;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

I think the problem is creating the content object and the XML isn't being attached correctly (maybe).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Doesn't it compile? Or do you get runtime errors? Which errors?

Comment: The request is sent but the service that handles the inbound request thinks there is no data and therefore returns "Unauthorised Access" which is the default response for that service.

Comment: Use Fiddler and check what is sent over the wire...

Comment: @fretje Thanks for the steer on using Fiddler. After much difficulty, I've now managed to get fiddler working and capturing the request/response of each approach. There are 2 differences. The working code has <?xml version="1.0"?> in the raw data and the content type is text/xml. The non working code doesn't include the <?xml version="1.0"?> and the content type is set as application/xml. My next step will be to work out how to change the content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to know the reason why the one approach doesn't work and the other does but I just don't have the time for any more digging. {:o(

Anyway, here's what I found.

A failure occurs when the content of the request is created using the following

```
HttpContent content = HttpContentExtensions.Create(root, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

But it works correctly when you create the content like this...

```
HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(root.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

The final working function is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate the user credentials held as member variables
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the user credentials are valid, else false</returns>
public bool ValidateUser()
{
    bool valid = false;

    try
    {
        // Create the XML to be passed as the request
        XElement root = BuildRequestXML("LOGON");

        // Add the action to the service address
        Uri serviceReq = new Uri(m_ServiceAddress + "?obj=LOGON");

        // Create the client for the request to be sent from
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Initalise a response object
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            #if DEBUG
            // Force the request to use fiddler
            client.TransportSettings.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            #endif

            // Create a content object for the request
            HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(root.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

            // Make the request and retrieve the response
            response = client.Post(serviceReq, content);

            // Throw an exception if the response is not a 200 level response
            response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();

            // Retrieve the content of the response for processing
            response.Content.LoadIntoBuffer();

            // TODO: parse the response string for the required data
            XElement retElement = response.Content.ReadAsXElement();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(Category.Serious, "Unable to validate the user credentials", ex);
        valid = false;
        m_uid = string.Empty;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpClient.Post` method has an overload that takes a `contentType` parameter, try this:

```
// Make the request and retrieve the response
response = client.Post(serviceReq, "text/xml", content);
```

Comment: Thanks. As you can see below, I was on the same thought process. The problem I have appears to be related to the way the content object is created rather than the post method used.