# .NET Soap Client WSDL with no defined methods

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've hit the internet pretty hard for this one over the past couple of weeks. I haven't used SOAP in a very long time and last I did all my wsdl service references worked. So here's the problem. I try to generate a service reference from the provided online wsdl (java based JAX-WS I think). This service does not allow the GET verb for the metadata so it fails there. I then downloaded the wsdl and fixed the directory issues pointed it at the right xsd's and viola it worked, however there's no methods to be found in this service, I'm supposed to just post a specific soap xml document to a url. The kicker here is I need to use the provided X509 certificate to sign the content and append a header to said xml using ws-security. Has anyone ever had an issue with adding service references or web references that don't have methods to attach to?

Comment: It the generated web/service reference sufficient to create request XML at least?

Comment: What do you mean there are no methods? Do you mean that there are no operations in the WSDL, or that "Add Service Reference" did not generate any methods?

Comment: Yes sorry there are no operations, the only operation I know of is the base address of the service. Yes I have a sample XML document

Comment: If there are no operations, then this is not a valid WSDL.

Comment: No argument here, but It's a requirement for me to make it work soooo welcome to my world. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some real-world "SOAP" services and service/client mixes necessitate cobbling together integration strategies.

"We publish our service, request, and response descriptions with WSDL...but provide no service operations" is classic unfortunately.  I call these single-implicit-operation services.

Consider using `HttpClient` to POST your `text/xml` content to the service.  Answers to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5952597/1810429) may be a good place to start.

When you turn to signing the request content, check out this [SO question about signing XML with an X.509 cert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1195728/1810429).

For the WS-Security header check out yet another [SO question about adding a WS-Security header to a SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734355/1810429) that may help.

Comment: Seems as though without operations I can't generate a working service reference to sign the client request anyway.

Comment: @Holyprin: Since your request will simply be XML text and you just need to sign its content as I understand your challenge, this is doable without a service reference.  See the second link I provided for details.

Comment: right, I just need to generate the SOAP:Header ws-security xml to apply to the actual xml before I send it. The third link uses wcf client bindings to achieve this.

Comment: @Holyprin: Good call regarding the 3rd link. I think I just had too many darned tabs open in Chrome: I have updated it to link to the post I intended, which provides a starting point in C# rather than WCF per se.

Comment: I'm actually looking into building the custom service contracts now myself using the templated code from generating a service that is similar. hoping it works out because I really don't want to deal with imp issues when they decided to conform to correct wsdl standards. Accepting your answer since I'm pretty positive it'll work.